# Reverse Vowels of a String

Tags: swift

The question is to reverse vowels of a string, like you input "hello", the output should be "holle".

I searched there's no such question in swift, so I want to post this as a discuss.

I wrote the code as below, and turns out it takes 12ms to reverse this "hello", anyone has any better solution by using swift features?

```
class Solution {
    func reverseVowels(s: String) -> String {
        if s == "" { return "" }
        let vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u","A","E","I","O","U"]
        var sVowels = [Character]()
        var reversedStr = ""
        for vChar in s.characters {
            if vowels.contains(String(vChar)) {
                sVowels.append(vChar)
            }
        }
        for char in s.characters {
            if !vowels.contains(String(char)) {
                reversedStr = reversedStr + String(char)
            } else if vowels.contains(String(char)) {
                reversedStr = reversedStr + String(sVowels.removeLast())
            }
        }

       return reversedStr
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add to [vacawama's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630618/vacawama) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39283021/3141234) solution:

Swift, unlike other popular languages (namely C# and Java), doesn't require all functions to be inside a class. `Solution` is a rather arbitrary class that doesn't need to exist. In Swift, you can write your function as its own free standing entity.

However, there's an even better swift approach. You can put your function into an extension to `String`, which leads to some pretty nice syntax:

```
extension String {

    static let vowels: Set<Character> = ["a","e","i","o","u","A","E","I","O","U"]

    func reverseVowels() -> String {
        if self == "" { return "" }

        var chars = Array(self.characters)

        let indices = chars.enumerate().filter{ String.vowels.contains($0.1) }.map{ $0.0 }

        let count = indices.count
        for i in 0 ..< count/2 {
            swap(&chars[indices[i]], &chars[indices[count - i - 1]])
        }

        return String(chars)
    }
}

"A test string".reverseVowels() //you can call your method directly on a string
```

I've made other improvements on the answer:

1. `vowels` can now be moved to be a static member of the `String` class, so that it's no regenerated on every invocation of `reverseVowels()` (though it's likely the compiler would optimize it to this).
2. `vowels` is now a `Set`, rather than an `Array` in order to use its faster version of `contains()`. This makes the function around **1.4x** faster, by my testing.
3. Switched to generating the `indices` array in a functional, immutable way.

Comment: I like the idea of making `vowels` a `Set`, but your code still has it as an `Array`.  How does the functional version of `indices` compare in performance to my version for a large string?

Comment: Thank you very much! This method is really inspiring, I always forget to use extension and I'm very confused with when I should use it, but anyway this is is good, Extensions! And yes, set, there is no need to make those vowel ordered. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @vacawama **1)** "but your code still has it as an Array" where? **2.** I'm not sure, I haven't tested it. Would you care to compare them?

Comment: I changed Array to Set for you.  See my edit. Sure, I'll compare them this weekend.

Comment: @FayeZhao I like to use extensions to convert calls from `verb(noun, noun, noun)`  to `noun.verb(noun, noun)`. This makes it clear which parameter is the subject, and which is/are the object(s): `subject.action(object, object)` instead of `action(subject, object, object)`

Comment: @vacawama Oh haha, thanks. I must've left it in by accident as a result of my back and forth testing.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is more of an algorithmic question rather than a Swift question. I don't know anything about Swift.

So here is my algorithm solution written in Java. Here are the main points you can use in your code:

1. Use a hash table to store the vowels. You can then perform lookup in O(1) time. I think in your Swift code, you are using an array, which can take O(n) time for searching.
2. Convert your input string into an array so that you can manipulate (swap) characters directly in the array rather than rebuilding a new string. In my code I create a new string only at the end.

```java
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ReverseVowels {

  public static String reverseVowels(String s) {

    // Create a hash table for vowels.
    Set<Character> vowels =
        new HashSet<Character>(
            Arrays.asList('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'));
    // Convert input string to array so that we can write into it.
    char[] result = s.toCharArray();

    int i = 0;
    int j = result.length-1;
    while (i < j) {
        if (!vowels.contains(result[i])) {
            i++;
        }
        else if (!vowels.contains(result[j])) {
            j--;
        }
        else {
            // Both are vowels.
            char temp = result[i];
            result[i] = result[j];
            result[j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    return new String(result);
  }

  public static void main(String argv[]) {
      System.out.printf("%s\n", reverseVowels("hello"));
      System.out.printf("%s\n", reverseVowels("qwetupoabt"));
  }
}
```

Output:

```
% java ReverseVowels
holle
qwatopuebt
```

---

Swift translation:

```
func reverseVowels(s: String) -> String {
    // Create a set for vowels.
    let vowels: Set<Character> = ["a","e","i","o","u","A","E","I","O","U"]

    // Convert input string to array so that we can write into it.
    var result = Array(s.characters)

    var i = 0
    var j = result.count - 1
    while i < j {
        if !vowels.contains(result[i]) {
            i += 1
        }
        else if !vowels.contains(result[j]) {
            j -= 1
        }
        else {
            // Both are vowels.
            let temp = result[i]
            result[i] = result[j]
            result[j] = temp
            i += 1
            j -= 1
        }
    }
    return String(result)
}
```

Comment: This is exactly how I'd do it. Try adding a swift version of your answer.

Comment: This is a good algorithm.  I up voted and provided a Swift translation.

Comment: This algorithm could be improved.  For a string such as "aexxxxxxxxxxx" it will repeatedly check if the first character is a vowel until it finds the other vowel to swap with.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
func reverseVowels(s: String) -> String {
    if s == "" { return "" }
    let vowels: Set<Character> = ["a","e","i","o","u","A","E","I","O","U"]
    var indices = [Int]()
    var chars = Array(s.characters)
    for (index, vChar) in chars.enumerate() {
        if vowels.contains(vChar) {
            indices.append(index)
        }
    }
    let count = indices.count
    for i in 0 ..< count/2 {
        swap(&chars[indices[i]], &chars[indices[count - i - 1]])
    }

    return String(chars)
}
```

Algorithm:

1. Make `vowels` to be `Set<Character>` to reduce conversions and speed up `contains` (thanks @AlexMomchliov for the `Set` idea)
2. Convert the string to `[Character]`
3. Find the locations of the vowels
4. Swap the vowels
5. Recreate the string from the `[Character]`

Comment: Great answer! I made some improvements in my answer you may want to check out.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

1 Pick up all vowels, and reverse them.

2 Map all vowels in the original String with the reversed vowels.

```
func reverseVowels(s: String) -> String {
    let vowelSet: Set<Character> = ["a","e","i","o","u","A","E","I","O","U"]
    var reversedVowelIterator = s.characters.filter{vowelSet.contains($0)}.lazy.reverse().generate()
    return String(s.characters.map{vowelSet.contains($0) ? reversedVowelIterator.next()! : $0})
}

print(reverseVowels("hello")) //->holle
print(reverseVowels("Reverse Vowels of a String")) //->Rivarso Vewols ef e Streng
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public string ReverseVowels(string s) {
    var start = 0;
    var end = s.Length-1;

    var vowels ="aeiouAEIOU";
    var result = s.ToCharArray();

    while(start<end)
    {
        while(start<end && !vowels.Contains(result[start]))
        {
            start++;

        }
         while(start<end && !vowels.Contains(result[end]))
         {
            end--;

        }
        var temp = result[start];
        result[start] = result[end];
        result[end] = temp;

        start++;
        end--;
    }
    return new string(result);
    
}
```